# css3 simple animate with transform and transition, a sudden jump at conclusion?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a simple animation like this:

```
.elem:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
-webkit-transition: all .4s;
}
```

When I hover, it scales correctly. But just when it was about to finish, it suddenly pops back to the former size and then snaps to the completed scaled up version.

How do I fix this?

Comment: it will help if you can provide a demo page via jsbin or jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

You have it a little bit wrong, you have to set the attributes a little differently:

```
.elem { -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out; }
.elem:hover { -webkit-transform: scale(1.3); }
```

You need to set the animation attributes on the element itself, and then the action on the hover :)

[Working example (Webkit browsers only)](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/zMRPK/).

Comment: i've given up on scaling but putting it in the :hover peusdo doesn't help.

Comment: Which browser are you viewing it in?

Comment: awesome. looked for this solution for 30 minutes before finding this one.